# Connection Between IOS and React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Can anyone help me with bridging an existing IOS app with the Blank react native application ? I am unable to call the UI class from React native upon a button triggers.

Comment: There is an official instruction/tutorial for this integration: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the tutorial and helped me creating a bridge.

http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-how-to-bridge-an-objective-c-view-component/